# What is the pravara and ancestral lineage of the kanakkayala Gotra?

Tags: history, gotra

I want to know the pravara of the kanakkayala gotra and the history of their ancestral lineage.

Comment: Pravara can't be figured from gotra, without some more info at hand. If you have a family purohita, he might help you out on that.

Comment: Isn't it a Reddy Gotra?

Comment: Yes, it's a Reddy Gotra

Comment: Yes, it's a Reddy Gotra. Can you provide me the pravara and sages associated with Kanakkayala gotra please